# Projection onto Basis Has Lower Error

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces, projection

Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a linearly independent subset of a separable but infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_X$, and let $y \in X-\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$.  Then if each $x_i$ is non-zero is it true that
$$
\min_{k_1,\dots,k_n \in \mathbb{R}}\|y-\sum_{i=1}^n k_ix_i\|_X<\|y -x_1\|_X?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\leq $ is obvious but strict inequaity may not be true. Consider the case when $%X$ is  Hilbert space, $n=1$ and $y=x_1+z$ with $z$ orthogonal to $x_1$. Then the square of  LHS becomes the infimum of $(1-k_1)^{2}\|x_1\|^{2}+\|z\|^{2}$. Clearly this infimum  is $\|z\|^{2}$ which is same as the square of RHS.

Comment: But what is a reasonable condition so that the $\leq$ is *strict*?

Comment: I cannot think any general condition for strict inequality. @ProbablyAHuman

Comment: What about in the case where $X$ is Hilbert?